# How can I fix the track fill image on my UISlider?

Tags: ios, uislider

I have a custom `UISlider` image for my track fill but it is going outside the bounds of the track.

Here is the code in my **AppDelegate.m**

```
UIImage *minImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider-track-fill.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 4, 0, 4)];
UIImage *maxImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider-track.png"];
UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider-cap.png"];


[[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackImage:minImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

[image: Slider Image]

- This is how it looks when I load my app

Comment: Have you tried just setting `clipsToBounds = YES` on your `UISlider`?

Comment: could you add the code? for this - I am having trouble doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to set clips to bounds = YES.

```
self.slider.clipsToBounds = YES;
```